# How to send post request to REST API CakePHP 3.6

Tags: reactjs, cakephp-3.0

Backend CakePHP 3.6 REST , frontend React

Request

```
Request URL: http://localhost/restcake/v1/posts.json
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 400 Bad Request
Remote Address: [::1]:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Reponse

```
code: 400
file: “PATHTO\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Controller\Component\SecurityComponent.php”
line: 351
message: “’_Token’ was not found in request data.”
url: “/v1/translations.json”
```

Request header

```
Accept: application/json    
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br    
Accept-Language:  en-US,en;q=0.9,mn-MN;q=0.8,mn;q=0.7    
Cache-Control:  no-cache    
Connection: keep-alive    
Content-Length: 68    
Content-Type: application/json    
Cookie:    csrfToken=1ca4d0479b6721049b17fa879e269816515cdd216e2f0a85a828dad33fa2bacf3a341f74b7d08b75ffa3b9fbebd0219914d50d30e6abeec45129c2fe39e1f7fa; CAKEPHP=pv2nkumt1a32urftf2jvq5nrrm; remember_me=Q2FrZQ%3D%3D.ZGYyNDNiMjdkOTRlNDMyZGVjYzhkMWUwZTE4MTJhOWJjZjBkZjEzODA5MWE2ZjJkOWRhN2RkNTg0ZjEwZDM4ML2ESQrHcOqYaNiMcRSYoK4WcuCAPx%2Fz7UgmA6cBU6pZXYnQX29kT2zUhGDCVlU%2F0ZPjlHtX7qiyIsuEwiCrmBonaNBD6G8QL4WMgap2QOieQ6KV%2BnQjRKz%2FYvzyuxwcia7ChJNdcvy1%2B9UzCSSLWX%2BDBR%2F1Qivlvc0Dl1HL6tX%2BaWWc6IfoT82wS331XCMUzcIo0yQzyVp595PkT%2F8NjXtyK3M%2BeB5bKy%2FMYCAIrXLJWVCse9NYACix35fST0unQ69FBxihlu0Wli%2BAT3NGQWo%3D    
Host: localhost    
Origin: http://localhost:4000    
Pragma: no-cache    
Referer: http://localhost:4000/    
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.92 Safari/537.36
```

I temporary disabled CORS in middleware.

Comment: Disable security middleware or component. Depends on cake version. If it is enabled you must present _Token value. More you can find here [https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/security.html](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/security.html)

Comment: Tnx for your reply. I don't prefer disable security component. What is correct way to set token in request header. Front and back-end separated.